# can't attached my ruby on rails project in vs code

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, debugging, visual-studio-code

I would like to debug in Visual Studio Code my ruby on rails project, with attach debugging, but my Visual Studio Code debugger doesn't stop at breakpoints.

- My ruby version:2.4.4
- My rails version:5.0.1
- My Visual Studio Code version    :1.35.1

I did install

1. ruby extension for Visual Studio Code
2. gem install debase
3. gem install ruby-debug-ide

and my configuration in launch.json is

```
{
  "name": "Debug Attach",
  "type": "Ruby",
  "request": "attach",
  "cwd": "${workspaceRoot}",
  "remoteWorkspaceRoot": "bin/rails",
  "remoteHost": "127.0.0.1",
  "remotePort": "3000",
  "showDebuggerOutput": true
}
```

***in debug console i get***

- "Debugger error: Client: Error: write EPIPE"

Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

Please try to add paths of bundle and ruby-debug-ide in your **launch.json** :

```
{
  "name": "Debug Attach",
  "type": "Ruby",
  "request": "attach",
  "cwd": "${workspaceRoot}",
  "useBundler": true,
  "pathToBundler": "/path/to/rubygem/wrappers/bundle",
  "pathToRDebugIDE": "/path/to/rubygem/gems/ruby-debug-ide-x.x.x/bin/rdebug-ide",
  "remoteWorkspaceRoot": "bin/rails",
  "remoteHost": "127.0.0.1",
  "remotePort": "3000",
  "showDebuggerOutput": true
}
```

I hope that helpful

Comment: thank you for your answer, but i get Property useBundler, pathToBundler, pathToRDebugIDE is not allowed.